# Filter ManyToMany over ManyToMany using queryset in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have some problems with django queryset which I can't resolve on my own.
I'd like to filter out the tasks which the user shouldn't see. The problem is that both the user groups and the categories are ManyToManyField and I don't know how to compare them.

My models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class Task(models.Model):
    # ... 
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    # ...

class Category(models.Model):
    # ...
    organizers_group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True)
    # ...
```

If the task could be only in one category I'd write something similar to this:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return queryset = super(TaskAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).filter(
        categories__in=request.user.groups
    )
```

But I have no idea what to do when using ManyToManyFields. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your queryset like:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    user_grps = request.user.groups.all()
    cat_lst = Category.objects.filter(organizers_group__in=user_grps)

    return queryset = super(TaskAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).filter(
    categories__in=cat_lst
    )
```